# Query on $\int \frac{dx}{\cos x \cos (2x+a)}$ .

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{dx}{\cos x \cos (2x+a)}$$

**MY APPROACH:**

I tried using partialization of fraction as follows :

$$ -\frac{1}{\cos a} \int \frac{dx}{\cos x} + \frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi-2a}{4}} \int \frac{dx}{\cos(2x+a)}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{\cos a} \cdot\ln|\sec x+\tan x| +\frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi-2a}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln|\sec (2x+a)+\tan(2x+a)| + c $$

I am dubious since I've never faced partialization of trigonometric fractions.  **Is it plausible?**
**Any other methods?**

Comment: @ResidentDementor How did you fix the first line...?  All seemed correct to me (Math Jax ).

Comment: Two of us edited almost simultaneously. You were missing a } at the end of the last \frac. I also put the \ before ln and removed the \times (which is not good for advanced mathematics) :)

Comment: OK got it..  Is suffered it earlier too... Thanks @TedShifrin.

Comment: But the math is wrong ;) You should check the equality you are using *before* you try integrating. Does it check?

Comment: @TedShifrin ...man,  I used my existing knowledge... I thought I nailed it... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$\cos(x)\cos(2x+a)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(x+a)+\cos(3x+a)\right)$$
Then use that

$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\frac{2tdt}{1+t^2}$$ the so-called Weierstrass substitution.
I will post you the solution for your work!
$$\sec (a) \left(-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sin (a)-1} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sin (a)-1} \sec
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(\sin
   \left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2}
   \left(\cos \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)}\right)-\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{\sin (a)+1} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sin
   (a)+1} \sec \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{a+x}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2}
   \left(\sin \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)}\right)+\log
   \left(1-\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\log
   \left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: I've tried that... But I don't know whether it would decompose or not... I'm not sure if any substitution would be feasible...

Comment: Aren't you missing some factors of $1/2$ inside the $\cos$ in your original identity?

Comment: And can you tell me where you missing these factors?